# Pickle linked objects

Tags: python, pickle

I want to pickle an object and a second object that references the first.  When I naively pickle/unpickle the two objects, the reference becomes a copy.  How do I preserve the link between the two objects `foo` and `bar.foo_ref`?

```
import pickle

class Foo(object):
    pass

foo = Foo()
bar = Foo()
bar.foo_ref = foo

with open('tmp.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(foo, f)
    pickle.dump(bar, f)
with open('tmp.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    foo2 = pickle.load(f)
    bar2 = pickle.load(f)

print id(foo) == id(bar.foo_ref) # True
print id(foo2) == id(bar2.foo_ref) # False
# want id(foo2) == id(bar2.foo_ref)
```

Comment: I don't think you can preserve object identity across separate pickles.  If you had a master object x that included foo and bar, and pickled that, when you unpickled it id(x.foo) == id(x.bar.foo_ref)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My previous answer was missing your point. The problem with your code is that you're not using the `Pickler` and `Unpickler` objects. Here's a working version with multiple dump calls:

```
import pickle

class Foo(object):
    pass

foo = Foo()
bar = Foo()
bar.foo_ref = foo

f = open('tmp.pkl', 'wb')
p = pickle.Pickler(f)
p.dump(foo)
p.dump(bar)
f.close()

f = open('tmp.pkl', 'rb')
up = pickle.Unpickler(f)
foo2 = up.load()
bar2 = up.load()

print id(foo) == id(bar.foo_ref) # True
print id(foo2) == id(bar2.foo_ref) # True
```

Comment: That was my suspicion, confirmed when I noticed that the documentation states that only instances of the `Pickler`/`Unpickler` classes have a `memo` attribute used to keep track of the pickled/unpickled objects. http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler.clear_memo

Comment: Simple and effective.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you pickle them together, the pickle module keeps track of references and only pickles the `foo` variable once. Can you pickle both `foo` and `bar` together, like this?

```
import pickle

class Foo(object):
    pass

foo = Foo()
bar = Foo()
bar.foo_ref = foo

with open('tmp.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((foo, bar), f)
with open('tmp.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    foo2, bar2 = pickle.load(f)

print id(foo) == id(bar.foo_ref) # True
print id(foo2) == id(bar2.foo_ref) # True
```

Comment: According to the documentation, that shouldn't be necessary, as `pickle` is supposed to keep track of the objects it has serialized and not repickle when references to already-serialized objects are made.

Comment: @JAB I thought that was only with a single call to dump, not multiple calls to dump on the same file?

Comment: This works, but if you want to be able to call dump multiple times, you can do that with the ``Pickler`` and ``Unpickler`` objects. See my other answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you do:

```
bar2 = pickle.load(f)
foo2 = bar2.foo_ref
```

Let pickle handle the link for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not handle the reference hierarchy manually.