# Is There a Pickler With a Memo That Doesn't Require a File

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

We have an interesting use case for Pickler in python.  We are doing multiprocessing with objects that have references to objects.

In this [question about pickling member objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376081/pickle-linked-objects) you can see that Pickler uses its memo to just load the original object instead of building a new object.  Is there some way to use a Pickler with its memo without Pickling to a file?

use example: (A, B, C all have smart hash and eq)

1. The master pickles an object A with sub-object B and sends A to a separate process
2. The child process returns a Picked object C that may also have object B
3. The master unpickles C and it smart enough to reference B and not make a copy

How about doing all this with cpickle?

Comment: As sort of a related question is Pickler smart enough in its memo to deal with member objects quickly?  If I pickle A with member B and C with member B does it pickle B twice?

Answer (score 0):

There are `dumps` and `loads` functions which use strings

```
>>> from cPickle import dumps, loads
>>> d={'foo': 'bar'}
>>> dumps(d)
"(dp1\nS'foo'\np2\nS'bar'\np3\ns."
>>> loads(_)
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

You can also use `dump`/`load` with a `StringIO` object

```
>>> from cPickle import dump, load
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> S=StringIO()
>>> d={'foo': 'bar'}
>>> dump(d, S)
>>> S
<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x20c3960>
>>> S.seek(0)
>>> load(S)
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Check the test in the question I link to.  Dump and load will make new objects when loaded.  The StringIO is interesting though let me play with that.