# Pickle linked objects part 2

Tags: python, class, pickle

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376081/pickle-linked-objects) but I dont get the expected results.
Here is my code

```
import pickle


def saveclass(objects):
    f = file(objects[0].name, 'wb')
    for obj in objects:
        p = pickle.Pickler(f)
        p.dump(obj)
    f.close()


def loadclass(name, size):
    f = file(name, 'rb')
    objlist = []
    p = pickle.Unpickler(f)
    for obj in range(size):
        objlist.append(p.load())
    f.close()
    return objlist


class class1(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class class2(object):

    def __init__(self, name, otherclass):
        self.name = name
        self.otherclass = otherclass

c1 = class1("class1")
c2 = class2("class2", c1)

print c1.name, ':', c1
print c2.name, ':', c2

print c2.name, 'has', c2.otherclass.name, ':',\
 c2.otherclass
print c2.name, "'s 'inside' class is c1:", c2.otherclass == c1

print 'saving classes'
saveclass([c1, c2])


print 'Reloading classes'

clist = loadclass("class1", 2)

c1 = clist[0]
c2 = clist[1]

print c1.name, ':', c1
print c2.name, ':', c2

print c2.name, 'has', c2.otherclass.name, ':', c2.otherclass
print c2.name, "'s 'inside' class is c1:", c2.otherclass == c1
print id(c2.otherclass) == id(c1)
```

The unpickled objects are not the same. Am I missing something?

In case of the otherclass being a list of other classes, should I do something different?

Comment: What do you mean "The unpickled objects are not the same"?

Comment: The class "inside" class2 before the loading is a class1 object with the name "class1". After loading the class "inside" class2 is different than the loaded class1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pickle the whole "universe" of interrelated objects in one `pickle.dump` call in order for them to get unpickled correctly.

Here's a version of your code that does this. (Of course `universe` could be a dict instead of a list with two items, but you get the point.)

```
import pickle

class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self, name, otherclass):
        self.name = name
        self.otherclass = otherclass

def test(c1, c2):
    print c1.name, ':', c1
    print c2.name, ':', c2

    print c2.name, 'has', c2.otherclass.name, ':', c2.otherclass
    print c2.name, "'s 'inside' class is c1:", (c2.otherclass is c1)

c1 = class1("class1")
c2 = class2("class2", c1)

test(c1, c2)
universe = [c1, c2]
pickled_universe = pickle.dumps(universe)
c1, c2 = pickle.loads(pickled_universe)
test(c1, c2)
```

output:

```
class1 : <__main__.class1 object at 0x01F6A830>
class2 : <__main__.class2 object at 0x01F6A870>
class2 has class1 : <__main__.class1 object at 0x01F6A830>
class2 's 'inside' class is c1: True
class1 : <__main__.class1 object at 0x01F6A8B0>
class2 : <__main__.class2 object at 0x01F71230>
class2 has class1 : <__main__.class1 object at 0x01F6A8B0>
class2 's 'inside' class is c1: True
```